# How to apply mask from array to another matrix in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

How you I apply a mask in numpy to get this output?

```
ar2 = np.arange(1,26)[::-1].reshape([5,5]).T
ar3 = np.array([1,1,-1,-1,1])
print ar2, '\n\n',  ar3

[[25 20 15 10  5]
 [24 19 14  9  4]
 [23 18 13  8  3]
 [22 17 12  7  2]
 [21 16 11  6  1]] 

[ 1  1 -1 -1  1]
```

--apply where ar3 = 1: `ar2/ar2[:,0][:, np.newaxis]`

--apply where ar3 = -1: `ar2/ar2[:,4][:, np.newaxis]`

The result I am after is:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [ 7  6  4  2  1]
 [11  8  6  3  1]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```

I have tried `np.where()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why `np.where` shouldn't work here:

```
>>> np.where((ar3==1)[:, None], 
...          ar2 // ar2[:, [0]],  # where condition is True, divide by first column
...          ar2 // ar2[:, [4]])  # where condition is False, divide by last column
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  4,  2,  1],
       [11,  8,  6,  3,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

I'm using Python 3 that's why I used `//` (floor division) instead of regular division (`/`) otherwise the result would contain floats.

This computes the arrays eagerly, so it evaluates `ar2 // ar2[:, [0]]` **and** `ar2 // ar2[:, [4]]` for all values. Effectively holding 3 arrays of the size of `ar2` in memory (the result and the two temporaries). If you want it more memory-efficient you need to do apply the mask before doing the operation:

```
>>> res = np.empty_like(ar2)
>>> mask = ar3 == 1
>>> res[mask] = ar2[mask] // ar2[mask][:, [0]]
>>> res[~mask] = ar2[~mask] // ar2[~mask][:, [4]]
>>> res
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  4,  2,  1],
       [11,  8,  6,  3,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

This computes only the necessary values which uses less memory (and is probably faster too).

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant, but here's what I could think of.

```
m = ar3 == -1
a = (ar2 // ar2[:, [0]])
a[m] = (ar2 // ar2[:, [4]])[m]

print(a)
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  6,  4,  2,  1],
       [11,  8,  6,  3,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```