# How to select columns from matrix in numpy with values from another vector

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

How can I select columns based on vector applied to matrix? 
Extension: 
[How to apply mask from array to another matrix in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781143/how-to-apply-mask-from-array-to-another-matrix-in-numpy)

```
ar2 = np.arange(1,26)[::-1].reshape([5,5]).T
ar3 = np.array([1,2,3,1,2])
print (ar2, '\n\n',  ar3)

results in:

[[25 20 15 10  5]
 [24 19 14  9  4]
 [23 18 13  8  3]
 [22 17 12  7  2]
 [21 16 11  6  1]] 

 [1 2 3 1 2]
```

What I am after is:

```
1  [[ 25  np.nan np.nan np.nan np.nan]
2   [ 24   19    np.nan np.nan np.nan]
3   [ 23   18      13   np.nan np.nan]
1   [ 22  np.nan np.nan np.nan np.nan]
2   [ 21   16    np.nan np.nan np.nan ]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create the mask with a ranged array comparison against `ar3` for assigning into those places and then assign `NaNs`. Since, the input is an `int` array, we need to make a float copy of `ar2` and then assign, like so -

```
out = ar2.astype(float, copy=True) # convert to float as NaNs are to be assigned
mask = ar3[:,None] <= np.arange(ar2.shape[1])
out[mask] = np.nan
```

For a case with a large number of rows and a decent number of cols, this should be a good method, otherwise slice into each row and assign `NaNs` limited by the corresponding `ar3` values.

---

Bit more explanation on the `mask` creation -

```
In [38]: ar3
Out[38]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2])

In [39]: ar3[:,None] <= np.arange(ar2.shape[1])
Out[39]: 
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comparing each element of `ar3` with the `range(5)` with that `outer` comparison gives us each row of the mask. If we look closely it's all `False` until that corresponding index value (ar3 value) and `True` thereafter. We need those `True` places for assigning `NaNs` and hence, this mask directly helps us in assgning NaNs in the entire output array.